# Mysql and java connection issue on ubuntu communication link failure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

Here is the scenario

I am trying to connect to mysql database server from the core java app using spring. My application and server runs on different box i.e. Have limited ports open

Here is what I have done soo far

1. I am able to telnet to port 5506 (on which my database server run ) from the client machine
2. I am able to connect to database server from command prompt(mysql client) from client machine

3.I tried all driver version from 5.0.8 to latest

1. and off course same code works on everywhere except production :)

Somehow I  started thinking that Java process required more ports to be open

Here is the exception

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:235)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:381)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:455)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(JdbcTemplate.java:498)
    at
```

Comment: Could you show us the URL you are using?

Comment: sure you can(need) hide/replace domain name // from security reason

Comment: if you have ssh access to instance with java service, Can you check access via telnet to your DB ? it can be over-configuring some firewall rules

Comment: jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://server:5506/db_production

Comment: I am able to telnet to 5506 and also I am able to connect to the mysql server from command line but it is more on Java app I am facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the 5506 port in the connection URL? This port is not the default one for MySQL (3306).

Comment: yes I have 5506 port on mysql and I am able to connect to this port from mysql command